# crossing / mutate is slow, how could i optimize this call?

Tags: r, tidyr

i have this call

```
distances <- crossing(nodes, gps_points) %>%
    mutate(dist = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(lon, lat), cbind(rlon, rlat)))
```

But it takes a long time to complete.
Just a crossing function takes 0.36 sec.
Whole Statement takes 2.587 sec.

Is it possible to optimize this call?

```
dput(head(nodes))
structure(list(ids = c(292376151, 1112377287, 6902561109, 5324247975, 
1112377281, 7018492265), ids_igraph = c(128974, 128973, 128972, 
128971, 128970, 128969), lon = c(11.831088, 11.830884, 11.8307377, 
11.8307106, 11.8305447, 11.8303853), lat = c(48.1111416, 48.1108747, 
48.1106855, 48.1106505, 48.1104559, 48.1102703)), row.names = c(833886L, 
2173435L, 4292366L, 4058008L, 2173434L, 4315822L), class = "data.frame")

 dput(head(gps_points))
structure(list(rlon = c(11.7989692, 11.7982155, 11.7968209, 11.7961655, 
11.7957267, 11.7944537), rlat = c(48.0742471, 48.0739067, 48.0733855, 
48.0730923, 48.0728656, 48.0722014)), row.names = c(3250429L, 
3250548L, 323901L, 3250542L, 3250544L, 323902L), class = "data.frame")
```

you can also download `node` and `gps_points` as csv or dput files here:

[node and gps_points csv files](https://gofile.io/d/ZcSF7y)

[node and gps_points dput files](https://gofile.io/d/IKZUJ7)

Thank you very much,
BR.

Comment: You can use `CJ` in `data.table` but I doubt if `crossing` is the problem here. Just run `crossing(nodes, gps_points)` and check how much time it takes as compared to the complete code.

Comment: How many nodes / gps points does have crossing to handle? Could you give a sample of nodes/gps_points dataframes?

Comment: so just a crossing function takes 0.36 sec.. Whole Statement takes 2.587 sec. nodes has 2018 rows and gps_points has 1151 rows.

Comment: some sample data would help for benchmarking

Comment: Hi Waldi and Wimpel, thank you for ou reply. I added a link that contains nodes and gps_points csv files.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to create reproducible examples. Also keep your examples as minimal as possible

Comment: Hi Sotos, i added dput files.

Comment: Copy/paste the output of dput in your question so we can simply copy/paste it in our sessions

Comment: Hi Sotos, i added the output in my question.

Comment: `geosphere` is quite slow. [`geodist`](https://github.com/hypertidy/geodist) is faster, and I believe the `geodist::geodist_vec()` function is the fastest implementation (and works well in `data.table`). Make sure to set `paired` and `measures` arguments to suite your needs

Comment: Thank you @SymbolixAU this improves the statement runtime dramatically. I selected "cheap" since i suspect that cheap means its the "fastest". The result still is different from geosphere::distHaversine() butt only by couple of meters.

Comment: yes "cheap" is the fastest and it implements [Mapbox's cheap ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler-cpp) calculation.

Comment: strangely i get this error now : R_cheap_paired_vec" not resolved from current namespace (geodist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `geosphere::distHaversine` to `geodist::geodist_vec()` with the setting `measure = "cheap"` to improve the runtime.